# Test resources not added to classpath

Tags: java, maven

The test resources aren't been added to classpath when building the project with Maven

The structure of project:

```
project/pom.xml
   /dist/pom.xml
        /src/main/resources/db/test.sql
   
   /test/pom.xml
        /src/test/com/loader/TestLoader.java
```

Here is pom.xml of dist module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>dist</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-test-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is pom.xml of test module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>dist</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And the JUnit test which tries to read test.sql from dist's module

```java
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TestLoader {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("db/test.sql").toURI());

        System.out.println(path.toFile().exists());
    }
```

When I run this test from IDEA, everything is OK, but when I try with command `mvn clean install`, I get error that resources are not found.

What could be the error?

Comment: Remove `<type>test-jar</type>` from the dependency declaration. You'd use that if you would import the test code of `test` into `dist`, not the other way around. Also your naming is inconsistent: your declare the module as `test1`, not `dist` in its pom.xml.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I removed `test-jar` from the dependency declaration, but this did not produce results. Module test1 it is parent module for modules dist and test. Here is repo with example https://github.com/azorinmsu/forstackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### File detection

`ClassLoader.getSystemResource()` will return a different kind of URL depending on how the test class is executed:

- from an IDE, it's a file ("file:/path/to/db/test.sql"), so `Path.get(uri)` is OK
- from Maven, it's a JAR (ZIP) entry ("jar:file:/path/to/dist-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/db/test.sql"), so `Path.get(uri)` throws a `FileSystemNotFoundException`

The URL is enough to know if the entry exists.
If so, its content can be read using `url.openStream()`.

```java
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("db/test.sql");
if (url == null) {
    // File not found
} else {
    try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

#### Maven configuration

Depending on the `dist` module's goal, 2 configurations are possible.

###### 1- `dist` is part of an API that will be tested in `test`

Then no need to use the `test-jar` execution goal at all.

- `dist/pom.xml` : the entire `build` section can be removed
- `test/pom.xml` : fine as it is

###### 2- `dist` is dedicated to tests only (in `test` module and maybe others)

Then, it's more consistent to put the `dist` resources in the test directory.

- `db/test.sql` should be moved to `dist/src/test/resources`
- `dist/pom.xml` : the `test-jar` part remains, but the `build-helper-maven-plugin` becomes useless and can be removed
- `test/pom.xml` : to make it work, a dependency `classifier` is mandatory

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>dist</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
</dependency>
```